# UITableViewController contentOffset returns nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to get the scroll position of my `UITableView`, however when I implement any of the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods, `contentOffset` always returns nil for me.

For example:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"offset: %@", [scrollView contentOffset]);
}
```

The log returns as `offset: (null)` when stopping a scroll motion in the simulator.

I can recreate this with the first example - SimpleTableView - in Apple's [TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html). The RootViewController is a `UITableViewController`, and if I place the above method in the implementation file this is what happens. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obviously I am new to this. It turns out the logger has no idea how to output a `CGPoint`, which is frustrating since it acts like it doesn't work by outputting null. In order to see the value in the log I had to do this:

```
NSLog(@"offset y %@", [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:scrollView.contentOffset.y] stringValue]);
```

Answer (score 1):

UITableView has a method rectForRowAtIndexPath which may be of interest to you.